# OSError at /media/<MultiValueDict: {}>

Tags: python, django

Django: I am trying to Upload Images from a User Form and save it to my Database. but I am getting an error which is

> OSError at /media/ [WinError 123] The filename,
>   directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:
>   'E:\pritish\myweb\myweb\media\'

These are my Code :

## My Form (HTML)

```
<form action="/python/contact/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}

            <h3 class="my-4" style="font-family: 'Acme';">Contact Me :</h3>
            <div class="form-group my-4">
                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name='name' placeholder="Enter your name" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group my-4">
              <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name='email' placeholder="Enter your email" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group my-4">
                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Phone Number</label>
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name='phone' placeholder="Phone Number">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group-sm">
              <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Enter your query</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" name='desc' rows="3" required></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Example file input</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" name="file">
              </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-4">Submit</button>

          </form>
```

At the very last I am taking an Image input

models.py

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    msg_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="")
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=10000, default="")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="python/images", default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def contact(request):
    messages.warning(request, "Hello Aliens")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name', '')
        email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone', '')
        desc = request.POST.get('desc', '')        
        contact = Contact(name=name, email=email, phone=phone, desc=desc, image=request.FILES)
        contact.save()

    return render(request, 'python/contact.htm')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image can not be `request.FILES`, it is `request.FILES['file']`, since that is the value for the `name="…"` attribute of your `<input type="file">` item.

You thus can construct a `Contact` with:

```
Contact.objects.create(
    name=name, email=email, phone=phone, desc=desc, image=request.FILES['file']
)
```

I would however advise to make use of a [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/), this can eliminate a lot of boilerplate code you are writing here.

In your `<form>` you also need to specify the encoding type if you pass files:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/python/contact/" method="POST">
    …
</form>
```

Comment: Still getting Error : MultiValueDictKeyError at /python/contact/ "file"

Comment: @PritishMishra: that is a different error, that is because you never specified in the form how to encode the files, and thus you never submitted any files :).